# Google Chrome access search engine settings from extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need access to search engines settings from Chrome extension to populate context menu with search engines list.
Extension operate as follows:
User select text, opens context menu with submenu "Search {selection} by ..." and get list of engines, click needed engine and go to relevant search url

Comment: There are very few Chrome Extension APIs that allow access to settings. Among the experimental APIs (which require special flags at launch), extensions can modify proxy settings, but not general preferences.

Comment: I need this function, too. Would you please contact me if you got a proper solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is going to manually build an extensive list of search engines that are displayed to the user. There is no pragmatic method of collecting currently installed search engines.

Comment: @zloidooraque This edit is not acceptable as it is not original author's intent. It would make more sense as a comment. I'm rolling it back.

Comment: @Xan I think you better discuss it with those, who accepted this edit. Also I think there is not a big deal (with all respect to author) what an actual author's intent was: SO is not a blog or something, it is intended to help people. And my edit actually might have been useful to those, who tried to resolve the same problem, topicstarter (and myself) had.

Comment: @zloidooraque I absolutely agree your information is _useful_. But you added it to the question in a wrong way (that would attribute the information to abraham). Since it's not a community-wiki answer, and your information is not a full answer, it's best to leave it as a comment - to the question, probably.

Comment: @zloidooraque If you look at [the review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8684723), by the way, you'll see other people agreeing with me. It's a question of attribution; it's not the author's intent to give this link, so you should either make an answer (bad idea if it's just a link) or a comment. Likewise, I think the information is useful, but I want _you_ to add it - so it's attributed to you.