# Is it possible for Chrome extension to access search engine settings?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My problem is quite the same as this one:

[Google Chrome access search engine settings from extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170451/google-chrome-access-search-engine-settings-from-extension)

But the latest answer of that one is about one year ago. Is there anything changed in last year? Perhaps some experimental APIs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome access search engine settings from extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170451/google-chrome-access-search-engine-settings-from-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, even in the experimental APIs there is nothing that allows access to general settings. Your best bet is to manually gather a list of search engines to which to you want to allow the user to send the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have seen (and I've looked).

Along with Fahd's suggestion, perhaps you could populate from [opensearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) links in pages the user has visited. Or prompt the user for opensearch links if they search sites that match engines from [mycroft.mozdev.org](http://mycroft.mozdev.org)?

I just want to sort the darn things ... import and export the darn things.  Maybe improve the UX a little (it sucks a little as it is).  At some point I monkeyed with accessing my own settings via SQLite, but I don't recall what I